# Node.js child processes to run python code not responding

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, express

I have an Express Node.js application, but I want to run python code (send data and receive results)
but when I'm testing it using postman still loading and I don't have any response.

my node.js code

```
    router.get('/name', callName);

function callName(req, res) {
    var exec = require("child_process").exec;
    var process = exec('python',["./hello.py",
                             req.query.firstname,
                             req.query.lastname
                          ] );
    process.stdout.on('data', function(error,data) {
      console.log('stderr: ', error);
        res.send(data.toString());
    } )
}
```

python code

```
import sys
# Takes first name and last name via command
# line arguments and then display them
print("Output from Python")
 print("First name: " + sys.argv[1])
 print("Last name: " + sys.argv[2])

# Save the script as hello.py
```

---

thank you @nijm I found the solution

- **first**  The child_process.exec method doesn't accept the command arguments as an array (like child_process.spawn does).
- **second**,

  u must have python installed on ur machine.
- **third**

  u must have python file in a public folder (in my case uploads folder)

  all these steps don't mention in any tutorial or an example about How to call a Python function from Node.js

**at the end of the day**, my code is

```
router.get('/name', callName);

function callName(req, res) {
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec(`python uploads/hello.py ${req.query.firstname} ${req.query.lastname}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
}
```

python code

```
import sys
# Takes first name and last name via command
# line arguments and then display them
print("Output from Python")
print("First name: " + sys.argv[1])
print("Last name: " + sys.argv[2])

# Save the script as hello.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method doesn't accept the command arguments as an array (like `child_process.spawn` does), try this (untested):

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec(`python ./hello.py ${req.query.firstname} ${req.query.lastname}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: thank you @nijm I used your code and I have this error message
(
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

I will try to fix this

Comment: You should probably replace `python` with the absolute path to the binary. You can find this by typing `which python` in terminal (on unix)

Comment: when I search google about error message ( 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.) they told me to install python on my machine after doing this I faced this error( exec error: Error: Command failed: python ../python/hello.py
(null): can't open file './hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory) I will try to fix this also :)

Comment: the error   (can't open file './hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory) I found that the python file must be in public folder to execute (in my case in uploads folder)thank you @nijm for your answer that leads me to the correct place to get what I want